# Как в PostgreSQL добавить строку, если такой еще нет

Tags: sql, postgresql

Нужно чтобы в таблицу добавлялось имя, если его нет среди существующих, в ином случае просто вернуть все имена,

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM names WHERE name = 'John') THEN 
   SELECT * FROM names WHERE name = 'John' 
ELSE 
   INSERT INTO names ('John')
```

Пытаюсь запустить в PostgreSQL такой код и получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запрос либо возвращает набор записей, либо нет. А возвращать или нет по какому-то условию - так не бывает в принципе. Соответственно вопрос - какие записи должны быть возвращены, если имя в таблицу добавилось. PS. Показанная конструкция может быть в коде хранимой процедуры, а не сама по себе. PPS. "просто вернуть все имена" у меня как-то не совмещается с `WHERE name = 'John'` .. PPPS. А почему проверяется 'John', а вставляется 'Jack'?

Comment: С John и Jack перепутал, когда менял данные, сейчас поменяю. Мне нужно добавить запись, если ее еще не существует, возвращать что-либо нужды нет, разумеется, если без этого можно обойтись. В одном вопросе данную конструкцию обсуждали для oracle, соответственно, думал, что она рабочая, но синтаксис не подходит для postgre.

Comment: Ну тогда тупо INSERT .. ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала надо добавить уникальный ключ для поля **name**

Чтобы PostgrSQL сам проверял наличие поля с таким значением и не позволял вставлять запись если запись уже есть.

В этом случае можно делать просто

```sql
INSERT INTO names ('John');
```

и обрабатывать ошибки при данном запросе.

Если ошибки обрабатывать не хочется или, вдруг, нет такой возможности, то можно изменить запрос

```sql
INSERT INTO names ('John') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Т.е. точно так же вставляется запись, но если она уже есть в таблице и возникает ошибка, то на эту ошибку сервер ничего не делает и продолжает работу дальше.

В качестве бонуса можно в случае конфликта например изменять какие-то другие поля в данной строке, которая уже есть в таблице

```sql
INSERT INTO names ('John') ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE <здесь изменение значения полей>;
```